# eventhandler delegate

Tags: delegates, c++-cx

i'm trying to create a timed event using the following code:

```
// SET UP A TIMER INTERVAL TO POLL INSTRUMENTS ONCE EVERY SECOND
DispatcherTimer^ timer = ref new DispatcherTimer;

timer->Tick += ref new Windows::Foundation::EventHandler<Object^>(this, &MainPage::Request_Data);

TimeSpan t;
t.Duration = 1000;
timer->Interval = t;
timer->Start();
```

I'm getting an error on this bit, specifically the **&**:

```
timer->Tick += ref new Windows::Foundation::EventHandler<Object^>(this, &MainPage::Request_Data);
```

The error is **Invalid delegate initializer  -- function does not match the delegate type.**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so my function I was passing to the EventHandler to be called was missing a few bits.

So I had declared this function as:

```
void MainPage::Request_Data(){

... stuff

}
```

which should have been declared as:

```
void MainPage::Request_Data(Platform::Object^ sender, Platform::Object^ e){

... stuff

}
```